# Plot items between date intervals

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this code in my Controller where I get all booking dates from my database `$newSchool`; and then I put them into `$events`; Now, How do I add those unavailable `dates/events` into `$events` in 3 months span where the `$newSchool` must be in the middle of that 3 months span?

i.e: if `$newSchool contains some events from September. I need to display those dates from August and October as well with the unavailable dates.

```php
$newSchool = DB::connection('mysql')->table('xdna_school_courses')
    ->where('status', '=', '99')
    ->where('type', '=', "school")->get();
$now = new DateTime();
foreach ($newSchool as $row) {
    $e = array();
    $e['title'] = "School";

    //get stills count
    $fCount = 14;

    $count = DB::table('stillcount')
        ->where('course_id', '=', $row->id)
        ->get();
    if ($count->isEmpty()) {
        $fCount = 14;
    } else {
        foreach ($count as $k) {
            $fCount = $fCount - $k->count;
        }
    }

    $cDate = new DateTime($row->course_date);

    if ($now > $cDate) {
        $e['description'] = 'Booking Done';
        $e['stat'] = false;
    } elseif ($now <= $cDate && $fCount <= 0) {
        $e['description'] = 'Course full.';
        $e['stat'] = false;
    } elseif ($now <= $cDate && $fCount >= 0) {
        $e['description'] = $fCount . ' stills left.';
        $e['stat'] = true;
    }

    $x = new DateTime($row->course_date);
    $e['fakeDate'] = $x->format('D, d M');
    $e['editable'] = false;
    $e['xDate'] = $row->course_date;
    $e['courseID'] = $row->id;
    $e['start'] = $row->course_date;
    $e['end']   = $row->course_date;
    $e['backgroundColor'] = '#FF1744';
    $e['borderColor'] = '#FF1744';
    $e['type'] = 'school';
    $e['partyCheck'] = $fCount;

    array_push($events, $e);
}
```